# Am I supposed do dispose the Image property of a UIImageView to help Garbage Collector in Monotouch?

Tags: ios, garbage-collection, uikit, xamarin.ios

On my quest to reduce memory usage, another question.
I see that `UIImage` and `CGImage` might be candidates for high memory usage in my app.
Wherever I use a UIImage, I try to wrap it in a using block to have it `Dispose()`'d as soon as possible.

However, often the `UIImage` ends up in a `UIImageView.Image` property.
If I remove the `UIIImageView` from its Superview, am I supposed to `Dispose()` the `Image` property before and set it to null or is this wasted typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am I supposed to Dispose() the Image property

**Quick answer:** No.

**Long answer:**

The `UIImageView.Image` property, [`image`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) selector, is retained. Even if you dispose it (from the managed side) the *native* retainCount (Objective-C is reference counted) of the `UIImage` will still be higher than 0 and the (native side of the) `UIImage` won't be freed.

When you dispose the `UIImageView` it will *release* the `UIImage` it use (Apple's Objective-C code) and, if the retainCount reach 0, it will be natively freed.

**If** there's a large delay between when you stop needing the `UIImage` and the time you dispose of the `UIImageView` then you might want to set `UIImageView.Image` to `null`. That will release (in the ObjC way, i.e. drop its retainCount by one) the `UIImage` and, if it's not used elsewhere, it will be (natively) freed.

Note that, if the `UIImageView` is not disposed, then setting its `Image` property to another `UIImage` will have the same result (the old one's will be released).

Comment: Merely setting the `.Image = null` will not release the memory before the next GC run. So if you really want to free that memory you'll need to `null` it and `.Dispose()` it. I've been through this with Instruments in hand ;-) (MT v5.2.11)