# Does every monotouch UIKit variable need to be at class scope?

Tags: xamarin.ios

In [this Xamarin forum post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/515), Xamarin admin `Clancey` says:

> But as a general rule, anything that has that type of interaction say
>   a UIButton, you really need to keep a reference to it.

For example:

```
//This can will blow up
public override ViewDidLoad()
{
    var myButton = new UIButton();
    myButton.Tapped += delegate{
        //do something
    };
    View.AddSubview(myButton);
}
```

This is because `myButton` goes out of scope and is GC'ed, but the underlying iOS button handle is still alive, and if ObjectiveC calls back to Mono with that button handle, the app crashes.  So you need to make `myButton` a class level variable, so it stays alive.

My question is: what about other kinds of UIKit objects, like `UIImage`?  Suppose I do this:

```
var image = new UIImage(sFilename);
ctlImageView = new UIImageView(image);

this.View.Add(ctlImageView);
```

`ctlImageView` is at class scope, but `image` isn't.  Can this cause the same kind of memory leak, and does `image` also need to be at class scope?  Or are `UIView` objects special in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to keep a reference to the `UIImage` because the `UIImageView` will hold one for you and clean it up when it is disposed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  But how would one know this, and how to generalize to other situations?  Are all objects that reference other objects guaranteed to do this?  I would have thought that adding a subview was like this, but apparently it is not.

Comment: Unfortunately the MT memory management documentation is pretty scarce, however, it's all pretty much driven by how the native side works. It's a dangerous game trying to generalise how memory is managed when dealing with memory starved apps, it's usually better to test these things out for yourself and make sure things get cleaned up as you expect - read the official apple documentation as a starting point. The long answer to your first question can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427467/am-i-supposed-do-dispose-the-image-property-of-a-uiimageview-to-help-garbage-col)

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you.  But now I'm worried about other things, like creating a CAGradientLayer in Monotouch, adding it to another layer, and letting the MonoTouch variable go out of scope.  There's no good way to test this, because I've been testing for months, but it *never* crashes for me, I just get sporadic and random reports of crashes, and no way to track down the reason other than theoretical reasoning, like what I asked about in my question.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank see Miguel De Icaza's (founder of Xamarin) answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338576/monotouch-mt-garbage-collector-how-to-correctly-release-my-views-class-members) it will give you a little bit more insight on how the MT GC works. You should also get familiar with the [profiler](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/monotouch_profiler) if you haven't already, that's a good starting point for detecting memory leaks.